# PHP Warning throws ErrorException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, dingo-api

A unit test is failing because an ErrorException about an undefined property is thrown. However, this happens in a connected shop system's core files which i cannot change.

My controller has a try ... catch block that catches the generic Exception object. But i don't want that catch to fire because of an undefined property.

I figured out the error is converted to an `ErrorException` in `HandleExceptions.php` in method `handleError`

**How can i make phpunit ignore notices and warnings coming from code pieces i can't touch?**

**What i've already tried**

In phpunit.xml

```
     convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
```

Set `APP_DEBUG=false` as well as `API_DEBUG=false` for dingo.

I am using Dingo 1.0.x with Laravel 5.4 and phpunit 5.7.26.

Comment: I've temporarily fixed it with catching a specific type of exception and setting error_reporting to `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);` in my AppServiceProvider's boot method if env=testing, but i am not sure, if this is a good idea :-)

Comment: Generally "code pieces i can't touch" would be mocked. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: @markdwhite The errors come from a closed source package, the shop systems core files you would never modify.

Comment: maybe there is a reason why mocking the object that is causing the problem is not suitable, though this would not involve modifying any source code. Mockery is part of Laravel and is pretty comprehensive, though I appreciate testing isn't always trivial to implement. So if mocking not helpful for you here, no biggie.